# Automatically add new posts to a specific menu name

Tags: menus

In the WP admin, Ive create two two menus Foo and Bar. On Bar, whenever a new post is made, it should go onto Bar but I only see the option for `Automatically add new top-level pages to this menu`. How to get the posts?

On Googling, I see examples creating functions in functions.php....I'm new to WP. Thanks?

Answer (score -3):

Posts are blog entries. They will post to your blog only.

Pages are to your site and listed like a normal website.

So you won't see blog posts on your page menus other than your blog name. 
To access posts simply go to posts in your dashboard